# Visual Studio 2010 -> Open javascript file (.js) -> Window shows garbled mess, rendering issue?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I haven't really had this issue at all with my current computer.  It just started happening the other day.  About half the time when I open a .js file in VS2010, it shows a bunch of junk versus a window of code when I open these.  If I close everything down and restart the issue is gone, but as the days go on I am getting tired of doing this on a daily basis.

Uploaded a picture below. :

[image]
Any help/info on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is saved as utf-8 and not ASCII?

Comment: Looks like a graphics drivers issue. Have you updated to the latest? VS uses hardware-accelerated drawing for many things.

Comment: Good question Cole, what is the standard there?  I didn't import the .js file I created it in VS2010 by adding new javascript file so it would be whatever is automatically created.  Good call Mahmoud.  I will post the answer to this solution briefly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you fix it via the options panel.  Thanks to Mahmoud for suggestion, wasn't thinking clearly.

[image]

Comment: No, you fix it by using proper drivers and not-broken video card.

Comment: Well if you need to keep working the above will allow you to view your files until you have time to work on the hardware.  Obviously, if you have all the time in the world you can work on your hardware.  Truly, not a bad point although very snarky.